# calculate the average cost

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do I get the average cost per visit in a TSQL statement?

I have the total count of visits and summed the cost.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `AVG` aggregate function:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177677.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Can't you simply divide the number of visits by the total cost?   (I.e., SUM(Cost) / SUM(Count))

Answer (score 0):

If you have the total count and summed cost, the average is just a division away:

```
 summed cost
------------- = average cost
 total count
```